# Keep duplicate rows in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset [lipid] that extracted from electronic medical record system (EMRS). In that EMRS, the physician give order to obtain a laboratory blood profile from a patient with a unique order number **BUT** with a different service types. So, if one order has 4 service types, EMRS will record the event on 4 rows (identical [duplicates] order number in Order_no column, **BUT** with a different service types in Service_type column) like this;

| Order_no | Service_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TC |
| 1 | HDL |
| 1 | TG |
| 1 | LDL |

Sometimes, one order may has <4 service types, hence, order will be like that;

| Order_no | Service_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TC |
| 1 | HDL |
| 1 | TG |
| 1 | LDL |
| 2 | TC |
| 2 | HDL |
| 4 | TC |
| 4 | HDL |
| 4 | LDL |
| 5 | TC |
| 5 | TG |
| 5 | LDL |
| 6 | TC |
| 8 | TC |
| 8 | HDL |
| 8 | TG |
| 8 | LDL |

What I'm trying to do is write a query that keeps orders that has four **identical** Order_no but **different** Service_type like this;

| Order_no | Service_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TC |
| 1 | HDL |
| 1 | TG |
| 1 | LDL |
| 8 | TC |
| 8 | HDL |
| 8 | TG |
| 8 | LDL |

How can I write this query in Google BigQuery?

Comment: sample data and expected result as a text - NOT IMAGE - would help!

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, how can I attach sample data?

Comment: check other questions to see how sample data and expected result is usually presented :o) - for example - this one  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72850244/5221944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below simple approach

```
select * from your_table
qualify count(*) over(partition by Order_no) > 3
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if you need to count ONLY distinct services - use below

```
select * from your_table
qualify count(distinct Service_type) over(partition by Order_no) > 3
```